# Selecting data from 2 columns and show in 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Can anyone help with the following: I have 3 columns in my database CARS.db and I am looking to show data in 2 columns.

3 columns:

| CAR | MODEL1 | MODEL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota |  | Celica |
| Opel | Astra |  |
| Honda | Accord |  |

How can I select from the table to show the following:

| CAR | ALLMODELS |
| --- | --- |
| Toyota | Celica |
| Opel | Astra |
| Honda | Accord |

Comment: You appear to have a normalization issue, as you have repeating columns. This should be store in rows not columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select car, coalesce(model1, model2)
from t;
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-`NULL` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use the COALESCE function to pick the first non-null value from a list of values
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Then use the NULLIF function to make the column MODEL1 null if it's empty
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Finally, don't forget to give an alias to the column with the AS keyword

```sql
SELECT CAR, COALESCE(NULLIF(MODEL1, ''), MODEL2) AS ALLMODELS
FROM t
```